# If 'IN' is shortcut for multiple 'OR's, what can be shortcut for multiple 'AND's in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck in a question related to MySQL. Taken query

```
select * from orders where customer_id in (256, 255, 236);
```

On various websites, under the explanation of IN operator, they have mentioned (e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) that IN acts like shortcut for multiple OR conditions.

Is there any kind of operator in MySQL that is for multiple AND conditions?

The above query will return all the rows related to customer_id 256, 255, and 236. But if I want to return only rows that are common to those three customer_ids, I tried following query.

```
select * from orders where customer_id = 256 and customer_id = 255 and customer_id = 236;
```

But this is not going to work, I know.

So I wanted to know if I can use shortcut for that multiple AND conditions (without using group by and having)?

Comment: Such a condition would always be FALSE. A column can't be 256 and 255 etc, at the same time.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: SQL does have the `ALL` operator which checks if value compares to _all_ values (comparison could be =, <>, >, < etc).

Comment: @jarlh My actual implementation of database is different and more complicated. So it will take a little time to post the demo data here. However, will show the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select o.order_id
from orders o
where o.customer_id in (256, 255, 236)
group by o.order_id
having count(distinct o.customer_id) = 3;  -- "3" = all customers
```

This requires aggregation (or `join`s or window functions) because you want to compare data on *different* rows.  A simple `WHERE` clause does not suffice in this case.

Comment: This is awesome. Earlier, I tried with something like `having count(order_id) > 1` to check the occurrences. But your approach is more valid. Thanks :)

Comment: I did not try it but what if an order have also 3 customer ids but sharing only one or two from those in the list...i think it woudl be select either though not having all three in the list?!